# Autolookup in grid view according to selected cell value

Tags: axapta

I have created a grid view of Leavemaster table and leaveApplication table. 
There is field LeaveId in LeaveMaster and foreign key in LeaveApplication table.

I want to, when I select leaveId in LeaveAppliation table, automatically have related fields like LeaveName be filled according to LeaveId.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the `leaveName` use a display method defined on the `LeaveApplicationTable`:

```
display EmplName leaveName()
{
    return LeaveMasterTable::find(this.LeaveId).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more fields to show consider using `outer-join`.
In the `LeaveApplicationTable` form add the `LeaveMasterTable` as a secondary datasource and use `outer-join` as the `joinMode` (`Allow-Edit`: false).

Add a `modified` method to the `LeaveId` field on the`LeaveApplicationTable` datasource:

```
public void modified()
{
    super();
    leaveMasterTable.data(LeaveMasterTable::find(leaveApplicationTable.LeaveId));
    leaveMasterTable_ds.refresh()
}
```

Also change the `validateWrite` and `write` methods of the `LeaveMasterTable` datasource to not change any data:

```
public boolean validateWrite()
{
     return true;
}

public void write()
{
     //super();
}
```